# how to duplicate Text box in Power Apps

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I need some help to see if I can duplicate a text box using Button in Power Apps. I have to the Text box and a button in my power apps, and what I am trying to achieve is if the users need more Text boxes, they click on the button, and the following text box will display.

[image]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll want to use a collection and a gallery to achieve this.

1. Create a blank collection

> ```
> ClearCollect(
>     colLinkGallery,
>     {Link: ""}
> )
> ```

[image]

2. Insert a gallery. Use the collection created above as the data source. Add a Text Input field and a button (and a label if you'd like)
   [image]
3. Set the Text Input control's default value to `ThisItem.Link`
   [image]
4. Set the OnSelect property of the button to

> Patch(
> colLinkGallery,
> ThisItem,
> {Link: TextInput1.Text} ); Collect(
> colLinkGallery,
> {Link: ""} )

[image]

5. Set the Visible property of the button to `IsBlank(ThisItem.Link)`
   [image]

When used it should look something like this:
[image]

6. At this point I assume you'd need to save the collection of links to a data source somewhere, however I'm not sure what your actual requirements are, so you'd need to explore this further.

Shane Young has some good videos on this concept which may be worth watching.

Part 1 here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgznk4XlPCo

Comment: Thanks for your message, I just need it to save back to SharePoint. I watched the Shane video and for some reason he has created two separate SharePoint list as I prefer to save everything in one list.

Comment: Without knowing what the structure of your SharePoint list (and PowerApp) looks like, it's hard to provide any decent guidance. I am assuming there is more to it than just these links. In that case, one option would be to concatenate all the values in "colLinkGallery" along with some sort of separating character and patch that back to your SharePoint list. However, using a child list would be a better option with simpler formulas. If all you're doing is saving these links as new individual list items, things would be quite simple.